# how to operate on two dataframes in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables 
1. stocks : number of bikes I have on that day 
2. sales : number of bikes sold last year on same day

I want to predict how many days I can sell my stocks based on last year data. 
For example if I have `80 units of KTM bikes on 2018-07-26` , then I can sell them in `3 days` .
How do I do this?

```
Ignore 2017-07-25 as this is more than one year old
on 2017-07-26 (80-15=65)
on 2017-07-27 (55-40=15)
on 2017-07-28 (15-50=-35)

so i can sell them in 3 days
```

i can sell RE in 1 day

```
stocks table
+----+----------+-----+
|Bike|      Date|Units|
+----+----------+-----+
| KTM|2018-07-26|   80|
|  RE|2018-07-26|   40|
+----+----------+-----+
```

Second table

```
sales table
+----+----------+-----------+
|Bike|      Date|Saled_units|
+----+----------+-----------+
| KTM|2017-07-25|         10|
| KTM|2017-07-26|         15|
| KTM|2017-07-27|         40|
| KTM|2017-07-28|         50|
| KTM|2017-07-29|         30|
|  RE|2017-07-26|         50|
+----+----------+-----------+
```

How do I do this with spark SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to get your desired output

1.Create `DataFrames` and rename the column of stocks `"Bike"` to `"Bike_Temp"`

2.`Group` the data of sales `dataframe` by `Bike` and collect remaining columns as `array<struct<string,int>>` using `aggregate` function

3.Finally join the dataframes  `agrouped_sales` and `stocks_temp` by `Bike` `column` like below

```
 val sales=Seq(("KTM","2017-07-26",10),("KTM","2017-07-27",15),("KTM","2017-07-28",40),("KTM","2017-07-29",50),("KTM","2017-07-30",30),("RE","2017-07-27",50)).toDF("Bike","Date","Saled_units")
 val stocks=Seq(("KTM","2018-07-27",80),("RE","2018-07-27",40)).toDF("Bike","Date","Units")
 val stocks_temp=stocks.withColumnRenamed("Bike","Bike_Temp")
 val grouped_sales=sales.groupBy("Bike").agg(collect_list(struct("Date","Saled_units")).as("date_saled_units"))
 val joineddf=grouped_sales.join(stocks_temp,grouped_sales("Bike")===stocks_temp("Bike_Temp"))
```

4.Create one `udf` and register it and write the logic to `count` no of days in `udf` like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import spark.implicits._

 def getNoOfDays(arr:Seq[Row],stock_units:Int):Int={
        val dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        //Setting last year date
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)
        val previousYearTodaysDate =dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()))
        //Iterating over collected list and converting arr<struct<>> to Seq[Date,Int]
        val dateBikeArr=arr.map(row=>(dateFormat.parse(row.getAs("Date").toString),row.getAs("Saled_units").toString.toInt))
        var noOfDays=0
        var totalUnits=0
        //In all the dates checkng for date which is greater than or equal to today's date and summing the total bikes
        for(tup<-dateBikeArr){
          if(tup._1.compareTo(previousYearTodaysDate)>=0)
          {
            totalUnits=totalUnits+tup._2
            noOfDays=noOfDays+1
            if(totalUnits>=stock_units)
              return noOfDays
          }
        }
        return noOfDays
    }

 val getNoOfDaysUDF=udf(getNoOfDays _)
```

5.Select the `column` Bike and `date_saled_units` on `joineddf` and call the `udf`

```
val outputdf=joineddf.select(joineddf.col("Bike"),getNoOfDaysUDF(joineddf.col("date_saled_units"),joineddf.col("Units")).alias("days_required"))
```

6.Sample Output:

```
+----+-------------+
|Bike|days_required|
+----+-------------+
|  RE|            1|
| KTM|            3|
+----+-------------+
```

I modified dates for testing purpose and assumed that you will always check for current date. Hope this will help you